# Scaling predictors in ARIMA model

Tags: time-series, correlation, forecasting, arima

If a predictor in an ARIMA model has much lower magnitude than the variable you are trying to predict, then do you need to multiply it by a scalar in order for it to be an effective predictor in the `xreg` argument for the model?

Comment: I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Answer (score 3):

The are no other variables in an ARIMA model besides the dependent variable. Perhaps you have in mind an ARIMAX model or a regression with ARMA errors.

Unless the scale of the predictor is sufficiently small to cause numerical problems, the scale should not matter. A coefficient on this variable will take account of the scale. That is, the estimated coefficient may be quite large if the predictor is associated with considerable changes in the dependent variable.

Alternatively, there should be no harm in scaling the variable. E.g. divide it by its standard deviation. Then you may interpret the estimated coefficient in the model as the effect associated with a change of one standard deviation (rather than one unit) in the predictor.

Answer (score 0):

Just addressing the term "need" without a theoretical underpinning, I would try testing and validating scaling. In my personal experience that answer would be no for my needs. For example if you are using (=,-,*,or /) then the variability capture should not change. This is different for non linear transformations.